# connect my html form to my js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to have a form collect numbers that will be the number of columns and rows on my spreadsheet, I created a form to collect this info:

```
<form>
        number of rows? 
            <br>
            </br>
        <input type="number" id="rows" name="rows" value="" />
            <br>
            </br>       
        number of columns? 
            <br>
            </br>
        <input type="number" id="cols" name="cols" value="" />
            <br>
            </br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
```

and I tried using:

```
let row = document.getElementById("rows")

let col = document.getElementById("cols");
```

to get the values added on the browser as my column and rows number but it's not working, what am I missing?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't tell us anything.  *are you getting an error?*  **Be specific**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: You shouldn't be using IDs if there are going to be multiple elements with the same ID. IDs should be unique.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how you are determining that "it's not working". What do you expect to happen? That JS is never going to have any visible effect.

Comment: Use a [validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). You have HTML errors.

Comment: FYI :  you have invalid `HTML`.  Also, where's your event handler?  You aren't grabbing the value after some action... you're just grabbing the default value of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You get the value of an existing input field with:

```
var row = document.getElementById("rows");
var rowValue = row.value;
```

To test: `alert(rowValue);`

Comment: when i console.log(row.value) nothing shows, its empty

Comment: That's probably because you initialize the input with `value=""`.  If you want to get the value that a user inputs, you need an event handler that fires on some action.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the `.value` attribute. It needs to look like this:

`document.getElementById("rows").value;`

Or - if you're using jQuery, simply `val();`

Answer (score -1):

It is OK to be a beginner. Everyone started somewhere... ;)

Please consider these pieces of advice:

1. **Do** not use `<br>` for presentation. Use CSS instead.
2. **Add** labels linked to your form fields.
3. **Wait** for the DOM to be ready. Using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) is a clever choice.
4. **Declare** event listeners to detect clicks and do some action in your handler.
5. **Use** `preventDefault()` to avoid browser redirection when you click a submit button.

Here is a working example:

```js
(function () {
  var rows = document.getElementById('rows'),
      cols = document.getElementById('cols'),
      submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
    
  submit.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
  
  function handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Rows: " + rows.value);
    console.log("Columns: " + cols.value);
  }
})();
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: left;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="rows">Number of rows?</label>
  <input type="number" id="rows" name="rows" value=""> 
        
  <label for="cols">Number of columns?</label> 
  <input type="number" id="cols" name="cols" value="">

  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Your first two points are irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: I don't fully agree. I see Stack Overflow as a collaboration tool where we learn and share. I would have loved to benefit from these simple pieces of advice when I was a student, so I thought it was a nice thing to include this information here. Moreover, the OP's code is invalid HTML, so IMO my recommendations are part of the question.